# Is there a way to implement video chat in a flutter Application with selectable AR Filters?

Tags: flutter, twilio, augmented-reality, agora.io

As per the title, I want to implement a Video chat app in a flutter project and use AR filters during video chat. I'm looking for an implementation that can be done easily so I've checked out Agora and Twilio flutter SDK's for Video chat but they haven't provided any ways to add AR Filters yet. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Is there a way to implement a separate AR filter SDK to the existing Agora or Twilio video chat Flutter SDK?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Followed a Github issue regarding the same: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/615

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't have any concrete answers for you here, but some ideas that might help. As a disclaimer, I am not a Flutter developer and the Twilio Video Flutter SDK is built by the community and not supported by Twilio, so your mileage may vary.

As far as I know, you can implement your own [camera source (iOS)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios-v4-configuring-audio-video-inputs-and-outputs) or [camera capturer (Android)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/android-configuring-audio-video-inputs-and-outputs) object that you can pass to the native Twilio Video SDKs. The camera capturer outputs frames that the SDK uses to send to the video room. If you can implement your own, then you can build whatever effects or filters on the frames before passing them onto the SDK.

Sorry this is a very vague answer, I hope you can apply this to the Flutter SDK and achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating AR filters using the Agora Flutter SDK needs to be done via the native layer of your Flutter application. Agora has various guides and blogs on how to add AR to your video calling application. You can refer to this Android blog that shows how to add face filters that might help you in your development journey: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/build-a-live-streaming-application-with-face-filters-on-android/